# Changing Joomla's Registration Process

Tags: redirect, authentication, joomla, registration, joomla3.2

I'm currently using Joomla 3.2 for a website project. I am trying to create a process that makes different page urls available to someone upon registration (not login).

For example; If you are someone that is interested in finding out general information on the business you would click on a button that says 'access this video'. A registration box would open up, you'd complete the process then press register; once it is done you would be redirected to that video.

This process would also need to work with other urls - so I can't apply a fix that just redirects a person to the same page.

Currently Joomla allows the person to register, but they must login and then they get taken to a profile page view. I need to keep the visitor on the right path basically.

Any suggestion are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is to login the person automatically once that person registers - this is probably the easiest thing to do and it makes more sense than doing it in any other way (note that you will still have to code the login part).

Comment: Do you have any process on how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could probably write a plugin for the onUserAfterSave event (since the registration will trigger a save) and then push the needed information into the session.

Answer (score 0):

In joomla backend you can set login redirect path.

I mean currently your login redirect url/path may be profile page.

you can change it to video page.

for more details please see     http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?t=729718

Comment: I want the redirect to happen as soon as someone registers, effectively eliminating the login step.